# Why doesn't SSH work after an apt-get upgrade?

Tags: ssh

I have recently updated the software on my Pi, using SSH, and when it was done,  I restarted it. I closed the PuTTY window and opened it up again, and clicked on the preset for my Pi. When it loaded, to my horror, it gave me an error: "Network Error: Permission Denied." The title of the window was, "PuTTY Fatal Error."

No big deal. Maybe the update somehow wiped out my SSH configurations that I just enabled via the `raspi-config` utility. (I set up a static IP using my router's settings page.) I then connected it to my TV, and enabled SSH again. When I plug it back to ethernet again, it gives me the same error.

I've seen this question: [SSH "connection refused" on Raspberry pi - cannot find why](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4709/ssh-connection-refused-on-raspberry-pi-cannot-find-why), but it doesn't really help me, especially because I'm not using the terminal, nor do I think that the SSH port should change. It seems to me by the error that somehow my router blocked something.

Since my TV is far away from my router, I can't find out if it's booting correctly. It's easy to do everything I want with SSH, that is except configuring SSH, most of which you can do without internet. :P

**Why isn't this working? Do I have to change a setting? Is the OS not loading correctly?** It boots fine without an internet connection. (Model B, R3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your firewall to make sure SSH is not being blocked.
If SSH was not working on the Pi, you'd get a time out error.

Comment: I updated the Pi, not anything else. Unless the Pi is behaving dramatically different while doing SSH, but that seems highly illogical.

Comment: No automatic updates got applied ? If you run a `lsof -i | grep ssh` on the Pi, that will tell you whether ssh is accessible. Do you have any other devices that you can use to check ssh connectivity ? Android Phone ?